# boolean database value giving Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am setting database values.... object[so on and so forth] is a specific column in my database... the code has worked perfectly and I added two new columns, FEATURED and ONHOLD... the following code gives me a warning entilted:

```
 Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

    object[PF_GROUP_USER] = [PFUser currentUser];
    object[PF_GROUP_NAME] = name;
    object[PF_GROUP_MEMBERS] = selection;
    object[PF_GROUP_FEATURED] = NO;
    object[PF_GROUP_ONHOLD] = NO;
```

Comment: bool should be passed as [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]

Comment: sweet... I know thats probably a silly question but that saved me a lot of time. thanks!

Comment: You can just do `@NO` and `@YES` to avoid the verbose `NSNumber` initializer